# Kubernetes Container Command to start an bash that does not stop

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to start a container with bash only. In other words, a bash that does not stop, i guess an interactive bash or shell .

So far when i put sommething like ["bash"] or ["bin/bash"] or simply bash, the container run and stop. Is there a way to start a bash that run continuously ?

## EDIT1

So far the only way that works for me is to write:

```
command:
   - tail
   - -f
   - /dev/null
```

## Edit2

My use case here is that i want to build a docker image simply to develop in it. So that image has all the tool i need to work.

Hence I wonder how such container should be start. I don't want to run any of the dev tool at start. I simply want the container to be available ready for someome to run the interactive shell at any time.

Comment: (1) You can't really interact with a Kubernetes pod's stdin or stdout, so running an interactive shell there doesn't make sense.  (2) "...to develop in it" isn't something that needs a cluster environment; use a plain Docker container, or install the tools you need on your local system without using a container at all.

Comment: >> ...to develop in it" isn't something that needs a cluster environment; ???
I don't understand that. I do have a use case, and good motivation for what i am doing. There is a big movement of in-cluster development for a reason. that you disagree with that, is your opinion, but i did not ask opinion about the rational of doing what i am doing, but rather the way to do it. This being said, thanks for your contribution

Comment: @MaatDeamon run `cat` command, without arguments it blocks forever.

Comment: @zerkms I tested and it does not work. After reading and starting to reduce my ignorance on the subject. It seems like it is due to the fact that there is no terminal attached, hence can would fail

Comment: @MaatDeamon I'm not sure what you mean by "it does not work". How and what exactly did you test? `cat` for sure would block forever and keep the container running, exactly as you asked.

Comment: My set up is a deployment in kubernetes. In the container spec i added to command cat as u suggested. You can try the container will keep restarting. The thing that unblock me to understand what is going among the many lecture i just did, is the following blog: https://devconnected.com/docker-exec-command-with-examples/ the section Docker Exec Interactive Option . From there i went to read a lot to understand better the notion of terminal and stdin and so on. So clearly, cat with nothing expect to read from STDin, but if there is no stdin available it will fail.

Comment: "When the cat command does not obtain any arguments, it waits for an input from a keyboard. If you try to run cat command lacking any arguments, cat will wait for your input from a keyboard until it receives an end-of-file ( EOF ) signal produced by CTRL+D key combination"

Comment: There is no TTY when you simply execute cat out of an interactive shell

Comment: Right, so just add `tty: true` to the container

Answer (score 2):

you can try the sleep command in while loop.

```
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", "while true; do sleep 10;done"]
```

Comment: I guess in the light of my learning, the question now is more, about what would be the less cpu consuming process. "while true; do sleep 10;done" or tail -f /dev/null ?

Comment: in both case the amount of cpu they are going to use you don't really need to worry at all.

Answer (score 1):

You create a container with

```
command: ["cat"]
tty: true
stdin: true
```

That way it would consume less cpu and memory than bash

Comment: Oh thanks, will try that. Did not know about the tty flag thing

Comment: What you just share is an interesting thing. Did some readying and it seems hardcore :) !! As in one of those thing that nobody explain clearly what is it for and what is happening un the hood. I mean, what tty does kubernetes attach your process to exactly. When you do docker run, it is attach to the one of your machine (client) ? Also why would someone generally speaking do that ? But this is probably another full flow question on its own

Comment: @MaatDeamon to be completely honest - I have no idea what it does :-) And I took it from the https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin code which I use with my jenkins server (so as you may have noticed - I haven't used it directly on my own before). That's what the `explain` says: `Whether this container should allocate a TTY for itself, also requires
     'stdin' to be true. Default is false.
` - as you can see - we also need to set `stdin: true`

Comment: @MaatDeamon in case you don't know that command yet: `kubectl explain pod.spec.containers.tty` `kubectl explain pod.spec.containers.stdin`